# How to write a Table-driven lexer by C#? (Based on Engineering a Compiler 2nd Edition book)

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, lexer

Recently, I am reading [Engineering a Compiler 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012088478X).

But I am struggling to understand the following pseudocode. I don't know how to implement this as C# code.

[image]

Unfortunately, I did not find any implementation for this book too.

Can anyone help me to convert this pseudocode to C# code?

Comment: This is probably too broad for a Stack Overflow question. If you start implementing it in C# and run into a specific issue, asking for help on that issue would be a better question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very complicated issue. That book is Procedural Oriented, and that fragment of code is more directed about detecting a single state.

But, C# is Object and Class oriented, good for describing models as "Lexers" and "Parsers". And, if you remember, these objects can be represented with with machines called "Automata".

Pseudocode:

```
public class LexerClass
{ 

}
```

Let's skip for a moment, details like the "constructor". This Automata or Lexer performs a main action, to detect several sequences of text called a "lexeme".

And assigns them a code number called a token.

The main operation is called "NextWord".

```
public class LexerClass
{
   void NextWord ( ) { }
}
```

This object has a state, that can have one of several values, that we will represent by an enumeration.

```
enum LexerStates
{
    S0,
    S1,
    S2,
    SE,
    SBad,
}

public class LexerClass
{
  LexerStates State;
}
```

They're several values that are used in the tables and the "NextWord" function, that sometimes are represented as text, but, also as number constants with a name called "enumerations", declared in programming as "enum".

Check that "NextWord" has other variables and values, such as "Stack" that stores "State" values, "Lexeme" that is a string.

The instructions "pop", "push", and "clear" are operations of the "Stack" object, and are written different in Object and Class programming like "Stack.Push( somestate );", instead of just "push somestate to" .

Note that "Bad" indicates, also a state, so we added as a possible value is states.

And, several tables, one with a Greek letter called "Delta"that looks like an 8 number, we will put them first as comments.

```
public class LexerClass
{
  LexerStates  State;
  Stack<State> Stack;
  String Lexeme;

  //TransitionTable DeltaTable;
  //Table CharCat;
  //TypeTables TypeTable
}
```

We cannot use the "Type" word because it has an special meaning in C#, and use the "DeltaTable" also.

Note, that the arrow to left "<-", means the assignment operation, and in C# is the single "=" operator, not to be confused with the double "==" equality operator.

Many books and other P.L. use the arrow to avoid confusion.

The token type table stores 2 values: "invalid" or "register". And at the end of the code there's a "return" with those values.

So, part of the code will be like:

```
public enum TokenTypes
{
  Invalid,
  Register,
  Other,
}

public class LexerClass
{
  //...
  TokenTypes NextWord ( )
     { return ... }
  //...
}
```

And the "CharCat" table uses some special values as columns, let's put it on an enumeration, watch that the digits, are together in a single column.

```
enum CharCatColumns
{
  R,
  Digit,
  EoF, 
  Other,
}
```

Note this table groups characters, "EoF" means the special "End of File" character. In compilers, it's assumed, that any file always finish with this character, even invalid empty files, are treated as they have it.

Besides, all these "enums" declarations, we are going to need the count of possible values an enum value can have.

```
const int CharCatCount = 4;
const int TokenTypeCount = 3;
const int LexerStatesCount = 5;
```

Let's start adding the tables.

```
public class LexerClass 
{
  TokenType [ ] /* var */ CharCat;
  LexerStates [  , ] /* var */ TokenType;
  TokenType [ ] /* var */ DeltaTable;

  void /* func */ Prepare Tables ( )
  {
    this.CharCat = new TokenType [ ] 
        { TokenType:: Register, TokenType:: Digits, 
            TokenType:;Other, TokenType:: Other };
    this.TokenType = new LexerStates [ ] in
        { LexerStates:: Invalid, LexerStates:: Invalid,
           LexerStates:: Register, LexerStates:: Invalid};
    this.DeltaTable = new LexerStates [ , ]
        { 
            { S1, SE, SE, SE, }
            { SE, S2, S2, SE, }
            { SE, SE, SE, SE }
         }
  } // func

} // class
```

And, let's start the main function.

```
bool /* func */ IsMemberSA
  ( LexerStates /* param */ AState)
{
   // ....
   return false;
}

LexerStates /* func */ NextWord ( )
{ 
    this.State = S0;
    this.Lexeme = "";

    this.Stack.Clear( );
    this.Stack.Push(LexerStates::SBad);

    while (this.State != LexerStates::SBad)
    {
      char /* var */ Char = NextChar( );
      this.Lexeme = this.Lexeme + Char;

      if (IsMemberSA(this.State))
         this.Stack.Push(this.State);
    } // while

    while ((! IsMemberSA (this.State) ) &&
        (this.State != LexerStates::SBad))
    {
      this.State = this.Stack.Pop( );
      Truncate (this.Lexeme);
      Rollback( ); 
    } // while

    if (IsMemberSA (this.State))
       return TokenType[this.State]
    else
       return TokenTypes:: Invalid;
} // func
```

The missing functions should be checked with other parts of the book.